# Statistical mean centering - Using total mean or attribute mean

Tags: statistics, centering, mean

I have a set of data, over 1000 rows and 20 attributes ( shown in columns ).
I am wanting use mean centering, which includes taking the mean away from each value to give a mean of 0. Do I remove the mean on an attribute by attribute basis, or do I remove the mean of all attributes from each?

For example, if the mean of attribute A was 500, and the mean of attribute B was 1,000.
For all values in A I could remove 500, which gives the A attribute a mean of 0. Then I could do the same for attribute B.

OR

I could take 750 off all values for both attributes.

Which is more statistically correct?

My question is due to this:
If I subtract different values from the different attributes, the attributes are then no longer comparable as different amount have been taken from each. If I subtract the same value from all, then some columns may be full of just negative figures ( and so negating the effect of mean centering ).

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would center each attribute individually.
If you center each attribute separately, you are assuming that for an individual, what matters is how each measure differs from the mean of that attribute, and you will lose absolute comparison of attributes for that individual.
For instance if you had person height, weight, centering them separately you could then ask "for a person taller than average, is the weight also larger than average weight". Averaging together height and weight would be meaningless.
One way to think about it is, you are creating an average individual, which you can now use as a benchmark against all your observations.
Now if the absolute value of 2 measures are comparable, say product price and cost, you wouldn't be able to compare them any longer, because they would be shifted. If what you care about is a measure that uses absolute comparisons for an individual observation, you would need to create an auxiliary metric, like for instance %profit. In that case, the centered values would allow you to ask "are products with higher prices more profitable than average".